# How can I ensure that a React component's state is correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, electron

I'm building a desktop application with Electron and React and would like to know the best way to validate a component's state or whether there is a better approach to this.

**Scenario**

Suppose that you have a subscription-based application that will display content depending on the user's subscription status. The first thing a new user sees is a sign in box. When successfully signing in, the application will fetch the user's subscription status from the database. If the user is subscribed, they will see premium content. If they are not subscribed, they will see free content.

A simple example of how the components may look is as follows:

**`Interface.js`**

```
class Interface extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            signedIn: false,
            hasSubscription: false
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...

    handleSignIn = (username, password) => {
        // ...

        this.setState({
            // signedIn: true | false
            // hasSubscription: true | false
        });
    };

    render() {
        const display = (this.state.signedIn) ? 
            <Content subscribed={this.state.hasSubscription}/> : <SignIn handleSignIn={this.handleSignIn}/>;

        return (
            {display}
        );
    }
}
```

**`SignIn.js`**

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit = (username, password) => {
        this.props.handleSignIn(username, password);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            // ...
        );
    }
}
```

**`Content.js`**

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    // ...
}
```

**Problem**

The problem with this is that the user may obtain subscription-only content by changing the state of `hasSubscription` in the `Interface` component.

**Question**

How can this problem be solved so that the state of the `Interface` component is accurate?

Comment: What do you mean the state is accurate? How can it be inaccurate?

Comment: I suppose it's the wrong word to use. What I mean is that the state (specifically the `hasSubscription` value) is equal to the user's subscription value in the database.

Comment: But when you do a request to get data from the database you get an accurate subscription value and set your state. So it will be accurate, right?

Comment: Using a Chrome extension such as React Developer Tools, any user can change the state of a component themselves. If you had a state variable called `isAdmin` which (when `true`) displays administrator-only content, a user could use this extension to change the variable to `true` without actually being an administrator. How to approach this is what I want to know.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean. You just need to add validations on the server to check if a current user has a permission to get that data.

Answer (score 1):

From a security perspective, in general, you should never trust browser-side JavaScript to tell you the truth, unless the server can verify it (precisely for the reason you have discovered - it can easily be tampered with). So, your server should not return any data to the client that the server itself cannot verify that the user should have access to. How you accomplish that depends on a lot of things in your tech stack. It sounds like you're already doing authentication and storing user permission levels in a database, so you should have your server perform the appropriate checks any time it returns data to the client application.